# htacces: how to rewrite URL only on a certain domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a small hosting company,

I want my main hosting domain to work with "www." always therefor I have this in HTACCESS:

```
# Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.givun\.co\.il
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.givun.co.il/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that I also have other domain parked that this script screws up the 
content that's delivered to them, it basically delivers the homepage.

Can this code be changed so that it rewrites only on the givun.co.il domain 
and not on parked domains?

any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but from I understand, you want to rewrite everything that is http://givun.co.il/... to http://www.givun.co.il/...

In that case, have you tried just searching for that as your condition?  ie:

```
# Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^givun\.co\.il
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.givun.co.il/$1 [R=301,L]
```